# How to delete an event with google apps script and sending an Email

Tags: javascript, java, google-apps-script

```
 function modifyevent(eventid,cal){
  var event = cal.getEventById(eventid);
  event.deleteEvent();
 }
```

This is working but not sending an email. Do you have an another way to do it with **GOOGLE apps script**. I would like to delete the event and send an email to attendees which is gonna delete the event from their calendar even if they are using a calendar such as outlook.

This is how I create the event if it can help:

```
function createEvent(date,start,end,summary,location,email,calendarId,incrementligne,ss){  
var newdatestart = new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), start.getHours(), start.getMinutes(), "0", "0");
var newdateend = new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), end.getHours(), end.getMinutes(), "0", "0");    
var invitelist = email.split(',');
var longueur = invitelist.length;
var event = {
summary:summary,
location: location,
description: '',
start: {dateTime: newdatestart.toISOString()},
end: {dateTime: newdateend.toISOString()},
attendees: [
{email: ''},{email: ''}],
// Red background. Use Calendar.Colors.get() for the full list.
colorId: 11
};
for(var i=0; i < invitelist.length;i++){
event.attendees.push({email: invitelist[i]});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Script Editor, go to 'View' - 'Show manifest file'. In 'appscript.json', add the following scopes:

```
 "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",             
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"]
```

Go to 'Resources -> 'Cloud Platform Project'. Click on your project name to open project page on GCP. Type 'Calendar API' in the search box at the top of the page. Click "Enable" on the Calendar API page.

Finally, use UrlFetchApp to call the Calendar API endpoint. One thing to note is that you need to modify the string returned by CalendarEvent.getId() to get the actual identifier without the '@google.com' part. I've tested the code below - everything works perfectly, including notifications.

```
 function deleteEvent(eventId) {

 var baseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId}/events/{eventId}?sendNotifications=true";
 var calendarId = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getId();
 eventId = eventId.substr(0, eventId.indexOf("@"));

 var url = baseUrl.replace("{calendarId}", calendarId).replace("{eventId}", eventId);

  var options = {

    "method": "DELETE",
    "headers": {"Authorization":"Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    "muteHttpExceptions": true

  };

  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();  
  Logger.log(res);    


}
```

Comment: Thank you it is a good way to do it however the goal was not only to inform the attendees that the event was deleted. In fact when the calendar API sends a notification or when we do it manually it also remove the event from the calendar for people who are using outlook or an other calendar.

Comment: You should've included more details in your question then. It was impossible to tell that you need a Java-based solution. Saying that something is a nightmare or doesn't work isn't really a question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just add details in the edit if the question was just to send an email a lot of topic already exists on stackoverflow the problem is that it will not delete the event from their calendar if they are using an other one such as Outlook they will have to do it manually. This is the method I want to use with google apps script : https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete

Comment: @amobox This is getting more confusing. What makes you think this is any better than calling event.deleteEvent() as in the example above? I thought you wanted to remove the event from Outlook. It doesn't seem that calling this API endpoint will affect your Outlook calendar in any way.

Comment: By using this I will be able to set sendNotification to true which will send an email to every attendees and by receiving the email (made by google) it  will automatically remove the event on opening on the outlook calendar.

Comment: In fact when sendnotification is set to true it is sending a type of email that outlook recognize and allows it to match it with the event related in the outlook calendar. Just like when you delete an event manually and google send a notification to the attendees. It will do the same thing but via google apps script.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GmailApp.sendEmail(String,String,String) method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)) (or [MailApp.sendEmail(String,String,String) method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)), depending of your needs), like:

```
function modifyevent(eventid,cal){
  var event = cal.getEventById(eventid);
  var name = event.getTitle();
  event.deleteEvent();
  GmailApp.sendEmail("mike@example.com", "Event deleted", "The event " + name + " has been deleted on " + now.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you it is a good way to do it however the goal was not only to inform the attendees that the event was deleted. In fact when the calendar API sends a notification or when we do it manually it also remove the event from the calendar for people who are using outlook or an other calendar.